# Visual Studio Online - How to show all projects and Team Rooms in one account url page

Tags: azure-devops

I have one project in my Visual Studio Online account which I can access with my account url: myname.visualstudio.com
Recently I have been invited to collaborate in another project which can be accessed from diffrent url: anothername.visualstudio.com.

How to show project created in this second account in my home page ?

Lets say that somebody posts something in Team Room (collaborated one). To find if something happened there I have to to go to that second address (complicated one) and enter team room there.  Can't this be done from my account url ?

If I will have many projects going then will I have to remember all those account urls and check them one by one every day?

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple projects, you can keep them all under the same VSO account umbrella by creating additional Team Projects.

Each VSO account (xxx.visualstudio.com) is totally independent from each other one -- they have no knowledge of one another and cannot "talk" to each other. In on-prem TFS terms, each VSO account is a totally separate team project collection.

So the basic answer to your question is "you can't". The bigger answer is "don't make separate VSO accounts, use multiple team projects within your existing VSO account".